# How to add Varnish VCL rule in Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, varnish, magento-cloud

I need to add a new VCL rule in my Magento Cloud 2.4, I'm using Fastly to have Varnish.

How could I customize my Varnish configurations in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Fastly, check if you're using the updated module. Then go on this page below to change it.

**Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Full Page Cache > Fastly Configuration > Custom VCL Snippets**

[image: Magento 2 Cloud VCL on Fastly]

Don't forget to click in **Upload VCL to Fastly**

[image: Magento 2 Cloud VCL on Fastly]